# C++ Why is my input validation crashing my program?

Tags: c++, validation

I have written a simple program that displays total jars of salsa sold, as well as the least and greatest types of salsa sold. The program works fine unless I intentionally use bad user input such as letters and negative numbers. The call to function inputValidation seems to work until I am finished inputting all the jars sold for each salsa type. Then it displays most of the results and crashes.

```
// this program allows a business to keep track of sales for five different types of salsa

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

// function prototype
int inputValidation(int);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    string names[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty" };
    int jars[SIZE];
    int totalSold = 0;

    // get the number of jars sold for each salsa
    int tempJars;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of " << names[i] << " salsa jars sold this past month.\n";
        cin >> tempJars;
        // call to input validation function
        jars[i] = inputValidation(tempJars);
        totalSold += jars[i];
    }

    // determine the lowest and highest salsa type sold
    int lowest = jars[0],
        highest = jars[0],
        leastType,
        greatestType;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (jars[i] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = jars[i];
            leastType = i;
        }

        if (jars[i] > highest)
        {
            highest = jars[i];
            greatestType = i;
        }
    }

    // display results
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "You sold " << jars[i] << " jars of " << names[i] << " salsa.\n";
    }
    cout << "You sold a total of " << totalSold << " jars of salsa.\n"
        << names[leastType] << " salsa sold the least amount of jars, which was " << lowest << " jars sold.\n"
        << names[greatestType] << " salsa sold the most amount of jars, which was " << highest << " jars sold.\n";
}

/*
    definition of function inputValidation
    inputValidation accepts an int value as its argument. It determines that the value is a number that is
    greater than 0. If it is not, then the user is prompted to input an acceptable value. the value is
    returned and stored in the corresponding element of the jars array.
*/

int inputValidation(int jars)
{
    do
    {
        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // return cin to usable state
            cout << "You may only enter non negative numbers. Please try again.\n";
            cin >> jars;
        }

        if (jars < 0)
        {
            cout << "You may only enter non negative numbers. Please try again.\n";
            cin >> jars;
        }
    } while (jars < 0);

    return jars;
}
```

Comment: Have you determined what line it crashes on?

Comment: Don't you think it's easier to simply use `std::getline()` to read one line's worth of input, convert it to `std::istringstream`, and only then use `>>` to parse the input, instead of doing all this fragile error handling on `std::cin`? Oh, and if all quantities are the same, `leastType` and `greatestType` will never be set, resulting in undefined behavior for `names[leastType]` and `names[greatestType]`, which is the likely reason for your crash.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, You were right. I initialized leastType and greatestType to 0 and my program seemed to operate just fine with good input and bad input. I assume that was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If `jars[0]` happens to be the smallest of the five, then `leastType` is never initialized and contains random garbage. Then an attempt to access `names[leastType]` exhibits undefined behavior.

Similarly, if `jars[0]` is the greatest, then `greatestType` is never initialized.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I believe this was the cause of my crashes. I initialized leastType and greatestType to 0 and the program seems to run fine now.